# Count number of weeks using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, count

I have the following sample dataframe:

```
Date                count_row   Work_Type
2018-07-31 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-08-01 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-08-01 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-08-01 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-08-01 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-09-02 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-09-02 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-09-03 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-09-04 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-09-04 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-09-06 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-09-07 00:00:00 1           logpage
2018-09-08 00:00:00 1           logpage
```

I want to break it down into weeks and count the number of occurrences in that week.  Specifically, I consider the beginning of the week to be Monday and the end of the week to be Sunday.

For instance, 9/3/2018 is a Monday (or what I consider to be the beginning of week).  So anything from that Monday to the following Sunday I count for 9/3/2018.

Below is the dataframe result I am looking for:

```
Beginning of Week Date (Mon)    count
7/30/2018                       5
8/27/2018                       2
9/3/2018                        6
```

I tried the following code:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

def take_first(array_like):
    return array_like[0]

output = df.resample('W',                  
                    how={'Date': take_first, 
                         'count_row': 'sum'}, 
                    loffset=pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-6))
```

This is the error I get:

```
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Answer (score 2):

A little timedeltarithmetic + `value_counts` should solve this:

1. Find the date offset in days from the start of week
2. Subtract the delta to get the beginning of the week
3. Count these values.

```
(df['Date'].sub(pd.to_timedelta(df['Date'].dt.dayofweek, unit='D'))
    .value_counts(sort=False))

2018-07-30    5
2018-08-27    2
2018-09-03    6
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resample`:

```
df.resample('W-Mon', on='Date', label='left', closed='left').sum().query('count_row > 0')
```

Output:

```
            count_row
Date                 
2018-07-30          5
2018-08-27          2
2018-09-03          6
```